# Does a latent class model become unstable with large samples and dimensions?

Tags: clustering, latent-variable, latent-class, finite-mixture-model

I have a dataset of approx 2million individuals with 40 dichotomous variables signifying presence or not of diseases (e.g heart disease, asthma, etc.) along with some sociodemographic info.

I have been attempting to assess if the co-existence of certain groups of diseases (e.g. individuals have heart disease, asthma, and high blood pressure) have a social pattern and have been trying to employ a latent class model to this data.

I was hoping to find certain latent classes of groups of diseases that I could then assess by sociodemographic breakdown.

Using the `poLCA` package in `R` based on a 1% sample of my data (to test code) I get some results that may be of interest (with 6 latent classes). When I increase the sample size to 10% (approx 200,000) individuals things seem to get more unstable (I got as far 17 latent classes giving the lowest BIC). These results are not particularly useful and in many ways meaningless.

Am I being silly attempting to run this method with such a large dataset? Would other Finite-Mixture models work? Should I go back to the drawing board and employ other forms of cluster analysis?

Comment: Have you duplicated the 6 classes with different samples?

Comment: Have you tried subsets of the variables, or considered dependence between them? In my work on heart disease, I've found that poLCA doesn't perform as well when you have variables that are too similar. A more obvious example is diastolic blood pressure and pulse pressure. The latter is the difference between diastolic and systolic pressure.